# React - state not getting updated after a prop being sent from another component

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

am having a trouble

i do have a popup in my `BrowseModalUpload` component and i had given state as

```
class BrowseModalUpload extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            modalIsOpen: this.props.browseAssetComponent ? this.props.browseAssetComponent : false,
...
}}
```

So initially there is no popup and when you click on one link , `setState` modalIsOpen to true and modal opens-thats the normal flow
And when i click in close window ,it `setState` `modalIsOpen` to false.

So i just clicked on popup it came and i click on close button it goes ,**now i click this popup from different component having prop browseAssetComponent as true ,it didn't open up**

code for modal is like this

```
<Modal transparent isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen} onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal} onRequestClose={this.closeModal} ariaHideApp={false}>
```

this this.state.modalIsOpen is still false,it not gets updated when i call the same from another component and this popup not coming up.

if you guys need more information let me know.
any help will be way to solve my roadblock

Comment: Are you reverting the boolean in this.closeModal? Can you post the entire component?

Comment: closeModal() {
  this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
 }
@User965207

Comment: I agree with the answers below so far but for your understanding, the reason it's not being updated is because when React creates the component it calls the constructor. When you pass new props to the component the constructor is not being called because the component is already instantiated. Instead the `componentDidUpdate` method of the React.Component class is being called with previous and current props.

Comment: @MarioSubotic so what will be the ideal solution for this

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example in codesandbox?

Comment: @midhunk Keep `modalIsOpen` state and a `toggleModalState()` function both in the  parent. Then you pass down both to the Modal component. In your Modal component you simply call props.toggleModalState on click wherever you need it. That was Modal doesn't need it's own state and is just reacting to the props it's being sent

Answer (score 1):

You can use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method where you can set the state based on the props.

```
    class BrowseModalUpload extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)
                this.state = {
                    modalIsOpen: this.props.browseAssetComponent ? this.props.browseAssetComponent : false,
        ...
        }
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
if(this.prevProps.browseAssetComponent != this.props.browseAssetComponent)
        this.setState ({
                    modalIsOpen: this.props.browseAssetComponent ? this.props.browseAssetComponent : false)
        }}
        }
```

Comment: This will cause infinite loop unless you add a condition. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: you are right @ssdh233. it will cause infinite loop

Comment: @User965207 can you explain bit more

Comment: componentDidUpdate LifeCycle method will get prevProps as input to the function. So when you update the component with new Props , we can compare the same with the Old Props and update only if the value is changed

Comment: am getting this error react-dom.development.js:25621 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define your props in state.

Better to pass directly like this

```
<Modal transparent isOpen={this.props.modalIsOpen} onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal} onRequestClose={this.closeModal} ariaHideApp={false}>
```

and handle from parent component function like this

```
handleModel=()=>{
  this.setState(prev=>({modalIsOpen:!prev.modalIsOpen}));
}
```

Check this example https://codesandbox.io/s/model-popup-o1z0p. I hope it will help you.

Comment: there are many scenarios where it depends on this.state.modalIsOpen and from parent only it depends on props. so we cant give like this always.
See within component what if i need to open and close ,the solution u told will fails,since it depends on state. `your condition will work if the control is coming from parent

Answer (score 0):

By doing this,

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    foo: props.foo
  }
}
```

you just initialized a state from a prop. **React doesn't sync the value of this.state.foo with this.props.foo for you.**

If you want to change your state when props are changed, you can do it in [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
 return { foo: props.foo };
}
```

However, if you read [the document of getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) carefully, you'll find React doesn't recommend to use this method in most of the situations. From your code, I don't really understand why `this.props.browseAssetComponent` would affect `this.state.modalIsOpen`. If you post the whole code I can give further suggestion.

Comment: i gave like this  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  this.setState({ modalIsOpen: props.browseAssetComponent });
   }
but its giving me error Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: for clarity: when you click on close modal ,state for modalIsOpen set to false. now again if i click to open the popup from some other component ,am just sending one param say browseAssetComponent as true and based on this value i need to make modalIsOpen to true ,but its not happening
why because Modal code is like this
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}>

Comment: @midhunk sorry, I didn't check the code carefully. The right way is to do `return { modalIsOpen: props.browseAssetComponent }` instead of `this.setState({ modalIsOpen: props.browseAssetComponent }`

Comment: Based on your description, what I would suggest is when you click to open the popup from some other component, directly set modalIsOpen to true in that onClick callback. If that "some other component" is not on the same level with modal, instead of passing a value from prop to state, you can [lift state up like this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: i found a workaround on this. I tried with your code,but its not showing popup. the code i tried is  
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if(newProps && newProps.browseAssetComponent){
  this.setState({modalIsOpen: newProps.browseAssetComponent});
  }
 }

Comment: I see, you are using an old version of React...getDerivedStateFromProps is kinda a replacement of componentWillReceiveProps on React 16